# empty tables when using many to many relations in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

when i want to update a list in jpa, the tables stays empty. no error at all. Getters and setters are present, just not listed here.

here my classes:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;


@ManyToMany
private List<Course> courses;

}

public class Course implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses")
private List<User> users;
}
```

And here my method which is saving the objects:

```
public boolean addCourse(User user, Course course){

    List<User> cas = new ArrayList<User>();
    cas.add(user);

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        course.setUsers(cas);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.clear();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using em.merge(course); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should add a `@JoinTable` annotation to define the many to many relationship on the owning entity, which in this case is `User` since the `mappedBy` element is pointing to the `courses` field on `User`.  The `@JoinTable` annotation specifies the `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` the relationship uses within the database.  You should also specify a `cascade` element on the `@ManyToMany` relationship.

**Here is an example.  Note that I have assumed some of your column names and that a junctiona table exists within the database.**

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;


@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="USER_COURSE", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID", referencedColumnName="COURSE_ID")})
private List<Course> courses;

}
```

**This example assumes that your database contains the following table**

```
create table USER_COURSE(
   USER_ID integer,
   COURSE_ID integer
)
```

You can also visit my blog where I covered this topic in this [post](http://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/10).

Comment: thx kevin, now the table is filled up. but the objects lists in the objects are still empty. to i have to rebuild the tables?

Comment: @Benj This may be caused by calling `clear` on the entity manager. Try removing that statement.

Comment: no, doesn't work. The next time i fetch a Course or User the Lists are empty. But the tables are filled up

Comment: sorry to dig this thread up .. but have you ever resolved that issue Benj?